# OpenGL Array Texture Not Using Correct Textures in Shader

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Edit: *I've tried both `glAttribIPointer()` and `glAttribPointer()` with the types of `GL_INT` and `GL_UNSGINED_INT`. Changing the value to a constant in the shader works (`fragColor = fragColor = texture(samplerArr, vec3(uv, 2));`), so passing the int to the shader seems to be the issue.*

That title's a mouthfull, but I think it explains pretty well the issue I'm experiencing. I've got this code that creates an array texture and is (hopefully) correct, as I can see some images. If I ask for the 0th image, I get the correct image, but if I use a texture id of any value larger than 0, the last texture in the texture array is the image I receive, not the expected. This is the code for creating the texture (the images can be seen, so I know the image to byte conversion works):

```
texture = glGenTextures();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // 1 byte per component
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST); // Pixel perfect (with mipmapping)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, images.length, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i ++) {
        InputStream is = Texture.class.getResourceAsStream(images[i].getFullPath());
        if (is == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not locate texture file: " + images[i].getFullPath());
        }
        PNGDecoder img = new PNGDecoder(is);
        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * img.getWidth() * img.getHeight());
        img.decode(buff, img.getWidth() * 4, Format.RGBA);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4); // 1 byte per component
        buff.flip();
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buff);
        Debug.log("{} => {}", i, images[i].getFullPath());
    }
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.error("Unable to create texture from path: {}", path);
    Debug.error(e, true);
}
```

I think most of that code is self explanatory, but I'd just like to make sure I'm doing it right. I then pass the texture id to the shader through this vertex attribute:

```
bindVertexArray();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuff, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_INT, false, 0, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
unbindVertexBuffer();
memFree(tBuff);
unbindVertexArray();
```

I think that is also correct, as I can pass the texture ID through and receive an output. That leaves one piece that could be wrong (but I still think is right for the same reasons), and that's the fragment shader:

```
fragColor = texture(samplerArr, vec3(uv, textureId));
```

Texture id is defined as

```
flat in int textureId;
```

and the sampler is

```
uniform sampler2DArray samplerArr;
```

I even tried passing through a uniform with the total number of textures in the array and using

```
fragColor = texture(samplerArr, vec3(uv, float(textureId) / float(totalTextures)));
```

instead, but that didn't change any textures.

I don't see anything wrong with any of those pieces of code (except for the last one), but I am new to array textures (and OpenGL in general), so I was hoping someone out there has had or has solved this issue so they can guide me to the solution.

Comment: IMHO there is no reason to flag this question for close. From the other hand, author of the question should probably get familiar with OpenGL in general before going to advanced topics like array textures

Comment: @MichaelIV I guess I should be a little more specific about my current OpenGL knowledge: I've been using it more or less for about 9 months, so I'm not lost, it's just that this issue has been driving me up a wall for two days, and I couldn't think of anything else to do. (This is my first time with array textures, which isn't helping)

Comment: Did you try for the starter to index into the array with hardcoded values in the fragment shader and see if you get correct texture layers?

Comment: @MichaelIV Hm, that actually fixed it, so it must have to do with the vertex data being passed either into the vertex shader or into the fragment shader, but that seems to be working fine (if I add a color variable or anything of that nature, I'm able to change it). Is there something else about passing `int`s into the shaders that I'm missing, even with the `flat` modifier?

Comment: I mean, I don't remember if it should be integer or float, but that division you're doing looks suspicious

Comment: Try `glVertexAttribIPointer` (notice the inner 'I') instead of `glVertexAttribPointer`

Comment: @MichaelIV The docs did say that the second parameter is automagically divided behind the scenes, so it should be an int. @Ripi2 LWJGL, I think, handles this separately, there's no `glVertexAttribIPointer` option, only the standard `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: @httpdigest I have tried GL30, that method's not in there, but I'll check again

Comment: @httpdigest Oh, yeah, `glVertexAttribIPointer` is in there, I guess auto import removed it before I tried it. Unfortunately, when using `glVertexAttribIPointer(2, 1, GL_INT, 0, tBuff);`, only the 0th texture is _ever_ used. I've also tried `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for both of those functions, but neither time did it yield any results.

Comment: I think it may just end up being the best idea to switch to a texture atlas, which I was avoiding in case I wanted to wrap textures or enable mipmapping or multisampling, but I can work around those. This issue is worse than being having to rework my shaders. Thank you everyone for your help